# pthreads, mq_timedreceive, pthread_cond_timedwait and CLOCK_REALTIME

Tags: pthreads, message-queue, condition-variable

I am working with a system that has implemented two posix functions

```
mq_timedreceive() and pthread_cond_timedwait()
```

Both of these functions use an absolute timeout based on CLOCK_REALTIME. This clock is getting changed at various times during system startup and can go backwards or forward by 10s of seconds to hours.

Open Group says:

> If the Timers option is supported, the timeout shall be based on the
>   CLOCK_REALTIME clock; if the Timers option is not supported, the
>   timeout shall be based on the system clock as returned by the time()
>   function. (mq_timedreceive)
>
> For cases when the system clock is advanced discontinuously by an
>   operator, it is expected that implementations process any timed wait
>   expiring at an intervening time as if that time had actually occurred. (pthread_cond_timedwait()).

However this doesn't give any guidance in the case where the clock is set backwards.

QNX solved this problem by providing

```
mq_timedreceive_monotonic().
```

> The mq_timedreceive_monotonic() function is a QNX Neutrino extension;
>   it's similar to mq_timedreceive(), but it uses CLOCK_MONOTONIC, so the
>   timeout isn't affected by changes to the system time.

Is there a  good way to achieve the QNX functionality in linux?

For mq_timedreceive() I can use mq_receive() and poll(). But for the condition variable I have not come up with a clean way. I could use itimer and signal but that seems way too complex.

The other solution, of course, is don't adjust the clock or use a different timeofday clock that is derived from CLOCK_MONOTONIC but I have no liberty to change the design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the clock used by `pthread_cond_timedwait()` on a condition variable by changing the clock attribute of the condition variable when it is initialised, using [`pthread_condattr_setclock()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_condattr_setclock.html).

Comment: Thanks!  I missed that. i don't think this is referenced in the pthread_cond_timedwait() doc other than oblique reference to a generic clock attribute. pthread_condattr_setclock() does cross-reference pthread_cond_timedwait(). It would be nice if mq_timedxxxx() functions  added this to the mq attributes in similar manner.